# How do you initialise a dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I achieve the dynamic equivalent of this static array initialisation:

```
char c[2] = {};  // Sets all members to '\0';
```

In other words, create a dynamic array with all values initialised to the termination character:

```
char* c = new char[length]; // how do i amend this?
```

Comment: Wow.. this turns out to be a great question. Lots of people unaware of std::fill_n it would seem.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not completely unaware of `std::fill_n`, it's just that I mostly ignore it, and only use _n algorithms when I have to. That is when the iterator type doesn't support `operator+`, and `std::advance` could be inefficient. Neither of those conditions is true of pointers.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
char* c = new char[length]();
```

Comment: I always forget this. Doesn't work for any other value, but then the questioner didn't ask for any other value...

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that before.

Comment: Likewise, never seen that; can you describe what's going on here?  What do you call this?

Comment: How do you redefine the size of this array?

Comment: Could you answer the question in C syntax? Thanks

Comment: @re3el: this question is about C++. You could ask a separate question about C, the answer is to use `calloc`.

Answer (score 36):

Two ways:

```
char *c = new char[length];
std::fill(c, c + length, INITIAL_VALUE);
// just this once, since it's char, you could use memset
```

Or:

```
std::vector<char> c(length, INITIAL_VALUE);
```

In my second way, the default second parameter is 0 already, so in your case it's unnecessary:

```
std::vector<char> c(length);
```

[Edit: go vote for Fred's answer, `char* c = new char[length]();`]

Comment: I am new to cpp and read that writing `int n; cin>>n; int arr[n];` is against the cpp standards. Does `int n; cin>>n; std::vector<char> c(n);` correctly follows the standards? Just wanted to know !!

Comment: @jay: yes, that's fine.

Comment: But `std::vector<char> c[n]` is against the standards. Right?

Answer (score 22):

Maybe use [`std::fill_n()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/)?

```
char* c = new char[length];
std::fill_n(c,length,0);
```

Answer (score 22):

The array form of new-expression accepts only one form of initializer: an empty `()`. This, BTW, has the same effect as the empty `{}` in your non-dynamic initialization.

---

The above applies to pre-C++11 language. Starting from C++11 one can use uniform initialization syntax with array new-expressions

```
char* c = new char[length]{};
char* d = new char[length]{ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

Answer (score 7):

Since c++11 we could use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
char* c = new char[length]{};
```

For an aggregate type, then [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) will be performed, which has the same effect like `char c[2] = {};`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has no specific feature to do that. However, if you use a std::vector instead of an array (as you probably should do) then you can specify  a value to initialise the vector with.

```
std::vector <char> v( 100, 42 );
```

creates  a vector of size 100 with all values initialised to 42.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it in one line easily. You can do:

```
char* c = new char[length];
memset(c, 0, length);
```

Or, you can overload the new operator:

```
void *operator new(size_t size, bool nullify)
{
    void *buf = malloc(size);

    if (!buf) {
             // Handle this
    }

    memset(buf, '\0', size);

    return buf;
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
char* c = new(true) char[length];
```

while

```
char* c = new char[length];
```

will maintain the old behavior. (Note, if you want all `new`s to zero out what they create, you can do it by using the same above but taking out the `bool nullify` part).

Do note that if you choose the second path you should overload the standard new operator (the one without the bool) and the delete operator too. This is because here you're using `malloc()`, and the standard says that `malloc()` + `delete` operations are undefined. So you have to overload `delete` to use `free()`, and the normal new to use `malloc()`.

In practice though all implementations use malloc()/free() themselves internally, so even if you don't do it most likely you won't run into any problems (except language lawyers yelling at you)

Comment: But... You can see std::fill / std::fill_n

Comment: The goggles...they do nothing

Comment: Probably because this is a strange way to approach the problem. The more canonical solutions are to use `fill_n` (`memset` is raw, `fill_n` is more generic, and to be consistent you would use it), a `vector`, or the shortcut-to-0 answer above. That said, your `operator new` could have a few improvements. Instead of malloc just use the regular `operator new`: `buf = ::operator new(size)`. That should automatically take care of all exceptions for you, and `new_handlers`. (Assuming the global `operator new` does that correctly)

Answer (score 1):

No internal means, AFAIK. Use this:
    memset(c, 0, length);

Answer (score 1):

and the implicit comment by many posters => Dont use arrays, use vectors. All of the benefits of arrays with none of the downsides. PLus you get lots of other goodies

If you dont know STL, read  Josuttis The C++ standard library and meyers effective STL

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize it "by hand" :

```
char* c = new char[length];
for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    c[i]='\0';
```

Comment: You could do this, but you don't have to. See above about std::fill() and std::fill_n().