# C++ error on char pointer

Tags: c++, char-pointer

I want to initialize a char* string, inside a struct.

this is the struct:

```
typedef struct __String  {
    char*    data;        // C-string data, 
    unsigned* copyRef;     // number of copy reference, delete only when the copyRef is 0
    bool     isACopy;     // this boolean is true when *data is a ref to an other MyString

  __String () {
      data = 0;
      isACopy = false;
      copyRef = new unsigned();
      *copyRef = 0;
      return;
 }

    void addCopyRef() {
        *copyRef++;
    }

    void removeCopyRef() {
        *copyRef--;
    }
 } *MyString;
```

and this is the point where it chrash..

```
void Initialize(MyString& string){

    string->data = new char[LENGHT];
    string->data[0] ='\0'; // this generate an error!
    string->addCopyRef();
}
```

this is the main:

```
MyString left_string, right_string, both_string;
Initialize(left_string);
Initialize(right_string);
Initialize(both_string);
```

the first one is going well, the second not..
could please you help me to understand where is the problem? thanks!

Comment: The name `__String` is reserved for the implementation, so you have undefined behaviour. Also `MyString` is a pointer type. How are you calling the function?

Comment: How was `LENGHT` defined? Did you mean `LENGTH`?

Comment: `MyString` is pointer, perhaps it is `NULL`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: also if I change it the problem still continue..

Comment: isnt new supposed to be new char(len)?

Comment: @Floris: Yes, I mean LENGTH, is in the .h

Comment: Spelled the same way in both cases, and defined as ...

Comment: @Pradheep, That would allocate memory for one character and initialize it to `len`.

Comment: @pradheep - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902011/whats-the-difference-between-new-char10-and-new-char10

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete example? (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: It compiles and run with no errors for me if I just do a simple main and call Initialize. Also - what's the point passing a reference to a pointer if you aren't changing it?

Comment: Added the main call..@Angew

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that naming a pointer type `MyString` is very very evil unless it's an actual C-string, and even then, it would still be pretty bad renaming it at all.

Comment: This is some funky mix of C and C++!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the objects before passing them like this:

```
MyString left_string = new __String();
Initialize(left_string);
```

As a general suggestion don't do such typedefs, they are very confusing and are error prone. If you do decide to typedef a pointer at least indicate it's a pointer in the type, i.e: `typedef struct __String* MyStringPtr`.

Comment: No it's not - MyString is a pointer(!) so no constructor is called.

Comment: typdef in short can ge read as `typedef struct __String* MyString`, thus MyString is a pointer to __String.

Comment: @TomerArazy, Yes, I didn't see the tiny asterisk after the class definition :/

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct __String  {
  char*    data;        // C-string data,
  unsigned* copyRef;    // number of copy reference,
                        // delete only when the copyRef is 0
  bool     isACopy;     // this boolean is true when *data
                        // is a ref to an other MyString

  __String () {
    data = 0;
    isACopy = false;
    copyRef = new unsigned;
    *copyRef = 0;
    return;
  }

  void addCopyRef() {
    *copyRef++;
  }

  void removeCopyRef() {
    *copyRef--;
  }
} *MyString;


void Initialize(MyString& string){

  string->data = new char[100];
  string->data[0] ='\0'; // this generate an error!
  string->copyRef = new unsigned();
  string->addCopyRef();
}

int main()
{
  MyString mystring = new struct __String;
  Initialize(mystring);
}
```

I tested like this without any error. with g++ on linux.
I think you'd better

- at least provide the error message here
- and your compiler and platform you work on.

I tested again with another main() below.

```
int main()
{
  MyString mystring = new struct __String;
  MyString mystring1 = new struct __String;
  MyString mystring2 = new struct __String;
  Initialize(mystring);
  Initialize(mystring1);
  Initialize(mystring2);
}
```

With this test code, there is no error.
I think you missed to instantiate an object which is pointed by `mystring` (In your code, `left_string`, `right_string`, `both_string`).
It would be the reason why, I guess.

And this code produce a memory leak from the constructor. In this state of code the constructor is not needed.