# C++ singleton with private constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I need singleton with a application lifetime, guaranteed creation/destruction and static access to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
    TypeName(const TypeName&);             \
    void operator=(const TypeName&)

#define M() C::sM()
#define M2() C::sM2()

using namespace std;

class C {
  private:
    static C* s;

    ~C() { cout << "~C()" << endl; }
    static C* instance() { 
        if (s==NULL) { s=new C(); }
        cout << "instance()=" << s << endl; return s; 
    }
    static void cleanUp() { delete s; }
    void m() { cout << "m()" << endl; }
    void m2() { cout << "m2()" << endl; }
    DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(C);
  public:
    C() { 
        cout << "C()" << endl; if (s==NULL) { 
            s=this; atexit(&cleanUp); 
            cout << "cleanUp is installed" << endl; 
        } else { 
            cout << "cleanUp is not installed" << endl; 
        } 
    }
    void* operator new(size_t sz) { 
        void* p=NULL; if (s==NULL) { p=new char[sz]; } else { p=s; }
        cout << "new(" << sz << ")=" << p << endl;
        return p;
    }
    void operator delete(void* p, size_t sz) { 
        cout << "delete(" << sz << "," << p << ")" << endl;
        if (p) delete[] static_cast<char*>(p); s=NULL; 
    }
    void static sM() { cout << "sM()" << endl; instance()->m(); }
    void static sM2() { cout << "sM2()" << endl; instance()->m2(); }
};

C* C::s = NULL;

int main() {
    M();
    M2();
    C* p1 = new C();
    C* p2 = new C();
}
```

But I don't know how to get rid of g++ warning:

```
test.cpp: In static member function 'static void C::operator delete(void*, size_t)':
test.cpp:22: warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined
```

If I write C* instead of void*, destructor start calling itself in infinite loop. Can anybody help me to get clean code without warnings? C++98 of course.

Comment: Why are you overloading `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Why do you think you want a singleton?

Comment: It's because I need to call default constructor only once.

Comment: Sure yes. It's for logging, configuration and other app's single instance objects.

Comment: Your `new` operator is leaking memory as you never return the pointer.

Comment: Yes. It works the same way. But I still don't know how to get instance of singleton using default constructor without deletion of allocated memory. Like moving default constructor to public section and calling it with C* p1 = new C(); C* p2 = new C();

Comment: Don't forget the square brackets in the delete.

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa Sure. I've lost them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type to delete is `char*`:

```
void operator delete(void* p, size_t sz) { 
    cout << "delete(" << sz << "," << p << ")" << endl;
    if (p) delete (char*) p;
}
```

There is a bug in your new: [What's the difference between new char[10] and new char(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902011/whats-the-difference-between-new-char10-and-new-char10)

Maybe should be:

```
p=new char[sz];
```

and then

```
delete[] (char*)p ;
```

---- edited:

The delete for purists, sacrificing clarity to people learning ;P :

```
delete[] static_cast<char*>(p) ;
```

(*actually I appreciate the note about the cast)

Answer (score 4):

The way I'm used to write singletons (whenever I really need one) is:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
     static Singleton& instance()
     {
          static Singleton theInstance;
          return theInstance;
     }

private:
     Singleton()
     {
     }
};
```

No need to mess around with overloading `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I think the OP has overloaded the operators as he wants to log every call to `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Snps Logging it in the con/destructor would be a better option.

Comment: @Dukeling Agreed, except for built in types.

Comment: @Dmitry That should be called when? `_atexit()` ? Simply register a friend function or s.th. like this. The instance's lifetime management will depend on how `crt0` is actually implemented (some implementations might not call `delete`for the singleton at all.

Comment: @g-makulik I've read a chapter about singletons in C++ in "Modern C++ design" by A. Alexandrescu and haven't seen other than _atexit option of destructing singleton.

Comment: @Dmitry `_atexit` might be fine as entry point to do the 'dirty work'. Register a friend or private static function that does it instead of using the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to overload neither `new()` nor `delete()`. 
And you probably do not need to hand out a pointer to your customers. A reference will do.

Construction and destruction of the singleton will be done in your `instance()`, which could look like so:

```
static C& instance() {
  static C _instance;
  cout << "instance()" << endl; 
  return _instance; 
}
```

This guarantees construction and destruction, because the constructor of C is called when the first user calls `instance()`, and only with the first call.
Destruction will happen at the end of your program.

Comment: It actually only guarantees construction (not necessarily destruction) AFAIK.

Comment: It guarantees construction and destruction (_The C++ Programming Language_, Stroustrup, 2000).

Comment: @g_makulik I am quite sure that destruction of static objects is guaranteed to commence after `main()` has ended, in the reverse order of the construction. This may be a little late if he has to do things in the d'tor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code should work if you just remove the `new` and `delete` overloads (which I don't really see the point of, if you want to log every con/destruction, do so in the con/destructors), but the below should fix your error.

Since you assign a `char*` to `p`, casting it to `char*` in the delete should work, i.e. `delete (char*)p;`.

However, I believe `p=new char(sz);` is making a char with a value of `sz` instead of a char array of size `sz`. For the latter, you may want `p=new char[sz];` and then `delete[] p` or `delete[] (char*)p;`.

Comment: @Dmitry You shouldn't really edit your question with all the fixes suggested in answers. That invalidates all those answers (which could lead to them getting downvoted or deleted), and it also invalidates your question if one of those fixes fixed your problem. Apart from (in general) formatting, indentation and possibly giving a shorter example reproducing your problem, you should generally make minimal to no changes to your code, especially if you're asking about errors. You should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) whichever answer you feel best answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. The question itself is invalid then.