# Dynamic memory allocation error

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

I have same problems with the below code.I try to read from file a destination.

```
void airplane::readFlight(void)
{
    char temp[100];
    ifstream f("date.txt");
    if(!f)
        {
            cerr<<"Err";
            //exit(EXIT_FAILUARE);
        }
    f>>nrFlight;
    for (int i=0;i<nrFlight;i++)
        {
            f.getline(temp,99);
            destination[i]=new char(strlen(temp)+1);
            strcpy(destination[i],temp);
        }
    f.close();
}
```

And i get this errors:

1. `invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’`
2. `initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’`
3. `Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:char * strcpy(char *, const char *)`

This error appears when i allocate memory and when i try to copy the information.
Thx.

Comment: What is the declaration of `destination`?

Comment: Sorry, What is `nrFlight` ?

Comment: strcpy(destination[i], temp) looks suspicious. Looks like it could be causing error 1. But what is the type of destination?

Comment: where did u declare destination?

Answer (score 1):

### Possibility 1

If you want to have a dynamic array destination with n elements of strings (instead of unformated char arrays) you should declare it first:

```
string* destination = new string [n];
```

and then you can use it:

```
char temp[100];
[...]
f.getline(temp,99);
destination[i] = temp;
```

don't forget to release memory:

```
delete[] destination;
destination = NULL;
```

### Possibility 2

If you want to use char arrays,then destination must be an array of char arrays (-> 2-dimensional). Declaration:

```
char** destination = new char* [n];
```

Usage:

```
char temp[100];
[...]
f.getline(temp,99);
destination[i] = new char [strlen(temp)+1];
strcpy(destination[i],temp);
```

Release memory:

```
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
   delete[] destination[i];
   destination[i] = NULL;
}
delete[] destination;
destination = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
destination[i] = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
```

See [What's the difference between new char[10] and new char(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902011/whats-the-difference-between-new-char10-and-new-char10)

I suspect you also have a problem with the declaration of `destination`. If you add that to the question, I'll add the correction here.