# Why a dynamically allocated char cannot be outputted?

Tags: c++

With reference to this thread: [What's the difference between new char[10] and new char(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902011/whats-the-difference-between-new-char10-and-new-char10)

I've this code snippet:

```
char *temp1 = new char(10);
printf("%s", temp1);
std::cout<< "tmp is" << temp1 << std::endl;
```

It dynamically allocates a single `char` initialized with an integer value of 10 and prints its value.

Why the code didn't output anything?

thk U all guys, I finally figure it out.

Comment: Display `*temp1` instead. (and `%c` format for `printf`).

Comment: Anyway, `char(10)` is actually `'\n'` so you will get an empty line

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: You are printing a non-null terminated C-string as null terminated string, so you have undefined behavior currently.

Answer (score 4):

A single char is not a string, and a pointer to a single char is not a string. Then you have the extra complication that 10 is the ASCII code for `\n` so you wouldn't be able to see anything even if your code was correct.

This code works, although it's not a good idea to mix C I/O and C++ I/O.

```
char *temp1 = new char(65); // ASCII for 'A'
printf("%c", *temp1);
std::cout<< "tmp is" << *temp1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: @Jarod42 I actually thought that might confuse the OP, which is why I just made a comment.