# initialize dynamic array elements to zeros

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

For a fixed array,

```
  // will initialize the missing elements to 0 as well
   A[max_row][max_col] = {0,}
```

Can we achieve this in dynamic arrays (multidimensional, in particular)?

**Side question**:  if we can't, and we are forced to use nested loop, then how does the initialization time of the trick above compared to nested loop initialization?

---

I don't want to vector, otherwise this question is meaningless. Thanks for the advise :)

Comment: why not use vector< vector<int> > for dynamic 2D arrays which you can initialize with default values ?

Comment: I know you can do that. Everyone wants to use vector, but I don't want to. I am sorry I forgot to include that. Thanks though.

Comment: Regarding your first question: What happened when you tried?  Regarding your second question: Internally C++ represents a multi-dimensional array as a single flat list of memory locations of type "whatever" (where whatever is how you invoked new).  You don't need a nested for loop if you do it that way.  You can just use a pointer to run through row x col number of positions with a single loop.

Comment: Why don't you want to? Just for understanding (practice), or for real use?

Comment: Exact Duplicate of [How do you initialise a dynamic array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029651/how-do-you-initialise-a-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: ok. In that case I am sure you are creating your 2D array using  malloc/new..right ? In that case you can value initialize with new operator or use memset for malloc. Eg "new int[ROWS]()" witll value initialie to zero

Comment: @DavidO.  Thanks for the response. It's clear.

Comment: @Als Thanks. Sort of (or maybe fully yes). The original poster worked on char, and I am working on numbers so at first I thought it would be different (for example, using memset).

Comment: @GMan  Yes. Sometime vector can introduce overheads that we don't want (maybe not). I am actually running a benchmark on several arrays so that's why I need a version on dynamic array.

Comment: @CppLearner: No. The overhead of a `std::vector` (if it even exists at all, which I believe it doesn't) is absolutely trumped by the gains in maintainability and program correctness.

Comment: @CppLearner: Welcome. In case you are doing some extensive benchmarking between the use of arrays and vectors..you might want to post your results in the FAQ section. And I agree completely with GMAN with his above comment

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure mine is small. I do plan on performing a research on this type of stuff in the upcoming semester. Thanks guys.

Comment: I get nervous when I see "is absolutely trumped by".  Of course it remains to be verified whether or not there is any measurable overhead when using vectors as opposed to arrays, but if there IS, such an absolute assertion is begging to find an exception.

Comment: @DavidO: It's silly to think I'm speaking in "true" absolutes; we aren't in Philosophy 101 any longer. :)

Comment: @GMan: Thank Socrates we're not in Philosophy 101. :)  Anyway, great answer below.

Comment: @GMan: I think we showed that vecter has no overhead in comparison to arrays here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/14065

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do this: `new int[N]() /* note parenthesis */`, then they are all zero initialized.

You should really use a `std::vector`, though.