# Fill dynamic array using curly bracket notation C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c++11, initialization

Is there a way in c++ to fill an array allocated like this

```
int **a = new int[4][2];
```

so that it's filled with values in one line like this

```
int a [4][2] = {{2,3,4},{5,6,7}};
```

Comment: Your first line isn't valid.

Comment: This has been asked many, many times, and the answer is still "no" (or `for (i = 2; i < 8; i++)`...)

Comment: @H2CO3 link to similar question?

Comment: @djechlin [Just the first Google hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029651/how-do-you-initialise-a-dynamic-array-in-c), there are better dupes, though (left to you as an exercise)

Comment: @djechlin it is a different question, not a duplicate

Comment: @rhalbersma it is a different question, not a duplicate

Comment: @Barmar it is a different question, not a duplicate

Comment: @femtoRgon it is a different question, not a duplicate

Comment: @JohnKraft it is a different question, not a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in C++11 with [universal initialization notation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519):

```
int(*a)[2] = new int[2][2]{{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Comment: +1 because I'm stuck on C++03.

Answer (score 0):

a vector of vectors would work, but only in C++11. I guess you'd have to give up C compatibility for that

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {{2,3,4},{5,6,7}};   
}
```

Comment: With a C++11 enabled compiler that supports initializer lists.

Comment: @Aeluned, yeah so Clang, gcc, Intel now, or MSVC anytime soon

Comment: @rhalbersma "or MSVC anytime soon" - you must be kidding.

Comment: @H2CO3 VC++ 2012 November CTP supports initializer lists, but not yet in the Standard Library (i.e. not for `std::vector`), so the RTM version will support it. I'm guessing that will not take long anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer std::array to C-style arrays if your compiler has adequate C++11 support:

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
}
```